# Replace repeated items with 0, keeping one instance - MS ACCESS

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I have a data set that follows a format similar to:

```
Purchase_Order  PO_Spend    Receipt_Date
PO1           200,000.00    12/19/2017
PO1           200,000.00    11/20/2017
PO2           30,000.00       2/5/2018
PO2           30,000.00       1/2/2018
PO3           45,000.00       2/7/2018
PO3           45,000.00     11/20/2017
PO3           45,000.00     12/21/2017
```

The data set is going to be used for reporting purposes, and I need to replace repeated purchase order amounts with 0 in order to avoid having the end user pivot the data set and incorrectly aggregating PO_spends.

I would like my data set to look something like this:

```
Purchase_Order  PO_Spend    Receipt_Date
PO1          200,000.00     12/19/2017
PO1                0.00     11/20/2017
PO2           30,000.00       2/5/2018
PO2                0.00       1/2/2018
PO3           45,000.00       2/7/2018
PO3                0.00     11/20/2017
PO3                0.00     12/21/2017
```

Any ideas on how to solve remove this duplicates? Anything from simple Access queries, to SQL for Access or VBA would do the trick.

Comment: This type of formatting is probably better done in VBA than in MS Access.

Answer (score 1):

Consider a correlated subquery wrapped in an `IIF` condition

```sql
SELECT p.Purchase_Order,     
       IIF((SELECT Count(*) FROM PO_Table sub
            WHERE sub.Purchase_Order = p.Purchase_Order
              AND sub.Receipt_Date <= p.Receipt_Date) = 1, p.PO_Spend, 0) AS [PO_Spend_Final],
       p.Receipt_Date
FROM PO_Table p
ORDER BY p.Purchase_Order, p.Receipt_Date
```

Alternatively, consider a `DCount` correlated calculation:

```sql
SELECT p.Purchase_Order,
       IIF(DCount("*", "PO_Table", "Purchase_Order='" & p.Purchase_Order 
                  & "' AND Receipt_Date <= #" & p.Receipt_Date & "#") = 1, PO_Spend, 0) As [PO_Spend_Final], 
       p.Receipt_Date
FROM PO_Table p
ORDER BY p.Purchase_Order, p.Receipt_Date
```

Be sure to update *PO_Table* to actual table name in all references.